# Localization (l10n) : Set Default Language for my mozilla addon

Tags: firefox, localization, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

I am developing a mozilla addon and implementing l10n. My questions are ,

- How to set default language to my addon?(This works when my addon doesn't support a language, it switches to default language)
- Will addon change its locale language when the language of the Mozilla Firefox changes?
- How to change my firefox browser language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Classic Bootstrap

In classic bootstrap addons, you don't set a default. Firefox automatically figures out the closest locale between the users browser and from whatever locales your addon has.

### JPM

Are you doing a JPM/SDK addon? If you are localizing the preferences, you have to initially set a string in the `package.json`:

```
"preferences": [
    {
        "name": "imagePath",
        "type": "file",
        "value": "",
        "title": "Image File Path",
        "description": "A path to an image on your computer that the dock icon should be set to"
    },
    {
        "name": "restoreDefault",
        "type": "control",
        "title": "default locale:Restore Default",
        "description": "this is from package.json:: If you have changed your icon, and want to restore the default Firefox icon, click this button",
        "label": "this is from package.json:: Restore"
    }
]
```

So the default is whatever you set there. If firefox cannot find a match to the locales provided it will use the string from package.json.

So for exmaple to localize the `restoreDefault` strings you would create a `en-US.properties` file and drop it in a folder named `locale` like this:

```
restoreDefault_title=blah Restore Default blah
restoreDefault_description=blahIf you have changed your icon, and want to restore the default Firefox icon, click this buttonblah
restoreDefault_label=blahRestoreblah
```

So now set your browser locale to english by going to about:config and then change the preference `general.useragent.locale` to something other then `en-US` (change it to `es`) for this example then load your preferences page (may need to restart browser after changing `general.useragent.locale`). Now because your addon does not have `es.properties` you will see the strings from package.json. Set your `general.useragent.locale` back to en-us and then restart your browser, and go back to your addon pref page, and you will see the strings from the properties file.

Comment: I need to use l10n in my panelScript. How could I do that? For Ex: On using l10n for the div of a panel document , where the content is based on a dynamic result.