# Forcing default l10n language in Firefox Extension

Tags: localization, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, l10n.js

I already read answers about placing a

> default.properties

file or a

> package.properties

, and even that the browser already detects the unique language as default, but it is not working.

I have my browser configured in french, and my partner had it in english. We are just implementing the extension in english, but when I run the extension in the french browser, it doesn not load anything.

I also read about having some properties in the package.json like:

```
"locales": {
        "en": {
            "name": "Open Web",
            "description": "Come on!"
        },
        "fr": {
            "name": "L'Open Web",
            "description": "Allez!"
        }
    },
    "default_locale": "en"
```

But didn't work.
I'm using last stable version of Firefox 42.0b1. Any idea?

Comment: That's weird, it should work. I need to see your full code, github would be an excellent place to share. Which answers did you read that you felt did not apply/work? Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168163/localization-l10n-set-default-language-for-my-mozilla-addon ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Noitidart I added some information. Thank you and sorry for the delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a default en-US.properties file. That's the default if the user language is not supported by your extension.