# Internationalization of preferences file in firefox addons

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am trying to internationalize my firefox addons, but i didn't succeed to do it with the labels of my menulist in my package.json file.

```
{
    "name": "style",
    "type": "menulist",
    "value": "a",
    "title": "my title",
    "options": [
    {
        "value": "a",
        "label": "my label for a"
    },
    {
        "value": "b",
        "label": "my label for b"
    }]
}
```

As said at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/l10n

The menulist and the radio preference types have options. The label attribute of each option is displayed to the user. If the locale file has a entry with the value of the label attribute prefixed with "{name}_options." as its key, where {name} is the name of the preference, its value is used as a localized label.

I've put this line in my locale files:

```
style_options.a = my translated label for a
```

I don't understand why I still have this "my label for a" when I open settings page rather than "my translated label for a".

**Answer :**
I thought that in the tutorial "value of the label" was "a" because "a" is the "value" associated with the "label", but I need to use the real value of the label, that give:

```
style_options.my label for a = my translated label for a
```

Comment: I didn't look into your problems in detail, however this is a very simple SDK addon I made that has the preferences localized - https://github.com/Noitidart/OS-X-Dock-Icon-Changer

Comment: Thank you, i've found it on another stackoverflow question. You do internationalization for preferences, but for menulist it is a little bit different.

Comment: Can you please share that link, for my info please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168163/localization-l10n-set-default-language-for-my-mozilla-addon

Comment: The tutorial and your example helped me to internationalize 90% of my package.json, but the way to do it with menulist labels listed on the tutorial didn't work for me (or I am doing it wrong).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link! I was hoping if you could share the code that worked for you. Can you please add that as a solution below.

Comment: The code that worked for me? For the internationalization of the labels of the menulist? Nothing worked yet.

Comment: I've found how to do it. Question has been updated.